# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taggit'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror, django-taggit

I used pip install to install django taggit, I am confirming that is there with pip freeze I am including taggit on installed apps and when I want to do the migrations it gives me this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taggit'`, I used pip freeze to confirm that is installed and is installed, I added it to installed_apps and is there as well

I tried to uninstall/ install try different versions and is not working it gives me always same error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taggit'`, even though is installed on installed apps and I confirmed with pip freeze that is on the directory, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I browsed to the site-packages of my **virtualenv**, noticed that "taggit" module was installed under a name like "django-taggit-3.1.0". Found the real "taggit" package inside it and cut and pasted the module, and it contents in the root directory of the site-packages of my virtualenv.
Instead of having a path like that ***"env/lib/site-packages/django-taggit-3.1.0/taggit"***, I'm having that ***"env/lib/site-packages/taggit"***.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have forgotten to activate the environment where `django-taggit` was installed when I was running a script (i.e. activated it in one console window, but didn't do it in the one I was running the `python manage.py runserver` script`).

Answer (score -1):

You have to install it with this command

> `pip install django-taggit`

Then add to your setting. bellow is what it should look like in settings.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'taggit',
]
```

here is a link to a video with more info about taggit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZywiX-Glu4

Comment: Your answer ignored the OP's description of what he has already done:
 "installed on installed apps and confirmed with pip freeze that it is in the directory" (I assume that meant it shows up in installed app in the environment when running pip freeze.